# How to used my own web service on push notification in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem in push notification 
I create certificate and write the code for device registration.Now I want to show push notification by using my web service.
It can be shown as like in this image[image]

How can I show like this notification using app logo image and message like.This notification is from android I need to show it in iOS.How to do this. I am using XML parsing.

My code.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)


    if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" ) )
    {
        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
        {
            // iOS 8 Notifications
            [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

            [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS < 8 Notifications
           [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
         {
             if( !error )
             {
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];  // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
                 NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
                 NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
                 NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
             }
         }];
    }


    //to check if your App lunch from Push notification
    //---------------------------------------------------
    //Handel Push notification
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        // Here app will open from pushnotification
        //RemoteNotification
        NSDictionary* dictionary1 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        //LocalNotification
        NSDictionary* dictionary2 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary1 != nil)
        {
            //RemoteNotification Payload
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary1);
            //here handle your push notification
        }
        if (dictionary2 != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from dictionary2dictionary2dictionary2 notification: %@", dictionary2);
            double delayInSeconds = 7;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                // [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary2 updateUI:NO];
            });
        }

    }
    else
    {}
    //------------------------------------------------

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"The generated device token string is : %@",deviceTokenString);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error.description);
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What you tried yet for that ? Show some code. what's your issue?

Comment: first write your code in iOS & let us know what are you not getting.

Comment: @anamika41 payload ????????

Comment: This is an example of payload: {
    "aps": {
        "alert": "joetheman",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "message": "Some custom message for your app",
    "id": 1234
}

Comment: @anamika41 Ya something like this. How to do this?

Comment: Just follow the steps in the link I mentioned.

Comment: @Muju, If this solves your problem Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is from where do you create your payload, and send. There are many third party tool that helps you create payload and push to your device. You have to register your device with it and upload the .p12 file. One such is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device) Please refer the link for steps.

Comment: But firebase is third party and it send notification as static. I need to use my server.

Comment: Why do you want to invent the wheel, when it is already there. There are alot of Push Notifications server which will be very easy. You can just send an event and based on the event it can create the payload and send it your devices.

Comment: I need to send my notification dynamically.